# Using cmov to implement C if / else if / else branchlessly, without any jmp

Tags: assembly, x86, micro-optimization

The task for me is to use cmov in assembly to implement the C code snippets, how can I jump to stop after every operation without using any jmp command? I am confused

C code:

```
if (x > y){
    z = x - y;
}else if (y > x){
    z = y - x;
}else{
    z = 0;
}
```

Assembly:

```
cmpl %eax, %ebx
cmovll %eax, %ecx    # x > y, z = x
subl %ebx, %ecx      # z = x - y

cmpl %eax, %ebx 
cmovgl %ebx, %ecx   # y > x, z = y
subl %eax, %ecx     # z = y - x

cmpl %eax, %ebx 
cmovel $0, %ecx     # z = 0
```

Comment: You don't need to jump because the other conditions then evaluate to false so you can fall through them. Basically you could rewrite the code without the `else` just like `if (x > y) z = x - y; if (y > x) z = y - x; if (x == y) z = 0;`

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear. So I need a way to directly stop the operation after one is done, in order to avoid falling through all the subtractions

Comment: I have just told you you don't need to do that because the other conditions evaluate to false so you **can** fall through them.

Comment: the c code is not allowed to change, I can only modify the assembly :-(

Comment: so nothing add between?

Comment: You don't need to modify the C code. I just showed that it is equivalent to that code. If any one of the conditions is true, no other can be true. Your assembly is broken though but not for this reason.

Comment: You only need two `cmov` instructions, and `cmov` with an immediate source isn't encodeable.  Actually only one `cmov` because `x-y = y-x = 0` in the case where they're neither > nor <.  This just calculates the absolute difference `z = abs(x-y)` without overflow.  Or for unsigned?  You don't say whether x and y are `int` or `unsigned`.